# is having customPartitioner helpful if I already implement hashcode for keys in Map-reduce jobs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hashcode, hadoop-partitioning

I am writing a custom `key` class, without `hashCode` implementation.

I run a `map-reduce` job, but during the job configuration, I set the `partitoner` class:
such as

```
        Job job = Job.getInstance(config);
        job.setJarByClass(ReduceSideJoinDriver.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, filePaths.toString());
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[args.length-1]));

        job.setMapperClass(JoiningMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(JoiningReducer.class);
        job.setPartitionerClass(TaggedJoiningPartitioner.class); -- Here is the partitioner set
        job.setGroupingComparatorClass(TaggedJoiningGroupingComparator.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(TaggedKey.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Here is the `partitioner` implementation:

```
public class TaggedJoiningPartitioner extends Partitioner<TaggedKey,Text> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(TaggedKey taggedKey, Text text, int numPartitions) {
        return Math.abs(taggedKey.getJoinKey().hashCode()) % numPartitions;
    }
}
```

I run the `map-reduce` job and save the output.

Now I comment-out `job.setPartitionerClass(TaggedJoiningPartitioner.class);` in the above job set up.

I implemented `hashCode()` in my custom class which is as follows:

```
public class TaggedKey implements Writable, WritableComparable<TaggedKey> {

    private Text joinKey = new Text();
    private IntWritable tag = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TaggedKey taggedKey) {
        int compareValue = this.joinKey.compareTo(taggedKey.getJoinKey());
        if(compareValue == 0 ){
            compareValue = this.tag.compareTo(taggedKey.getTag());
        }
       return compareValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        joinKey.write(out);
        tag.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        joinKey.readFields(in);
        tag.readFields(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return joinKey.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (this==o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof TaggedKey)){
            return false;
        }
        TaggedKey that=(TaggedKey)o;
        return this.joinKey.equals(that.joinKey);
    }
}
```

Now I run the job again (Note: I don't have any `partitoner` set). After the map-reduce job, I compare the output from previous one. They are both exactly same.

so My question is:

```
   1)  Is this behavior universal, that is always reproducible in any
        custom implementations? 

    2) Does implementing hashcode on my key class is same as doing a
    job.setPartitionerClass.

    3) If they both serve same purpose, what is the need for
    setPartitonerClass?

    4) if both hashcode() implementation and Partitonerclass
    implementation are conflicting, which one will take precedence?
```

Comment: Your partitioner has a bug and will fail if `hashCode` is negative.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: I fixed it using Math.abs. but that's not the point of the question.

Comment: Sure, that's why it is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the same result because your custom partitioner is doing exactly what the default one does. You are only moving code to another class and executing it there. Put in different logic like 
key().toString().length() % numPartitions
or something other than getting the hashcode() % numPartitions and you will see a different distribution of keys to reducers.

For example you can't get this partitoner just by editing hashcode()

public static class MyPartitioner extends Partitioner {

```
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {

        int len = key.value().length;

        if(numReduceTasks == 0)
            return 0;

        if(len <=numReduceTasks/3){               
            return 0;
        }
        if(len >numReduceTasks/3 && len <=numReduceTasks/2){

            return 1 % numReduceTasks;
        }
        else
            return len % numReduceTasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that both custom partitioner and default ones does the same thing. My question is not that. My question is by having a hashCode() method on my class, is equivalent to defining the partitioner (if both does the same)

Comment: Not always. The partitioner has access to the number of reducers so anything that plays with that information can't possibly be done from the hashcode method. Try to write a hashcode() method equivalent to the partitioner that goes numPartitions - hashcode()%numPartitions.

Comment: Should have said     numPartitions - hashcode()%numPartitions - 1 to make it a legitimate partition function that you can't write inside hashcode() but I think you see the point.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont see your point. Can you edit your answer above and give concrete example of what you mean here.